# Bitmap Factory Returns null when passing input stream

Tags: android

I am using the following code to get Bitmap from Bitmap factory but it returns `null`.

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
```

and I  am getting result string by following code:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams httpparams = httpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpparams, 60000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpparams, 60000);

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
/*
 * Reading the response from the Server
 */

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
inputStream.close();

responseData = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Why kind of data are you putting in? Bitmaps can be created from binary data and from UTF-8 encoding in your code I suspect you are filling it with string.

Answer (score 0):

`BitmapFactory.decodeStream` expects binary bitmap data to be passed in. If the input stream is `null`, or cannot be used to decode a bitmap, the function returns `null`.

From your code it is clear that you are passing textual data into `BitmapFactory` and that is the cause of failure. You have to decode that textual data into bitmap binary data before you pass it to `BitmapFactory`.

How to do that depends on how is bitmap data encoded into string on server side.